# How to alert a javascript function on a cell in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I disable a particular cell of my `gridview` on `page load` as follows

```
grdInvoice.Rows[grdInvoice.Rows.Count-1]
          .Cells[6].Enabled = false;
```

Now I would like to apply a javascript alert function for this cell

I tried this

```
grdInvoice.Rows[grdInvoice.Rows.Count-1]
          .Cells[6].Attributes.Add["onclick"]="f1();"
```

My function is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function f1() {
    alert('no more rows found to copy');
}
```

But didn't work for me ..

Comment: i think your attribute add method should look like this
grdInvoice.Rows[grdInvoice.Rows.Count-1].Cells[6].Attributes.Add("onclick", "return f1();");

Comment: I tried that too but didn't work for me

Comment: So if my understanding is right you want to execute a javascript function upon clicking the disabled gridview cell, please confirm!

Comment: Yeah on disabled cell I would like to apply

Comment: As you mention that you are doing these in page load can you try the same in gridview's row databound event in my case it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set attributes like below.

```
grdInvoice.Rows[grdInvoice.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[6].Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
grdInvoice.Rows[grdInvoice.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[6].Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:f1();");
```

Try this ..hope this will helps you..

Answer (score 0):

You can use RowDataBound event. like this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        int? index = Session["LastIndex"] as int?;

        if (index != null && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex == index)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "f1()";
        }
    }
```

But you should have last index value in session.

I don't know how you are binding your grid but one option is this:

```
    List<ClassName> data = GetData(...);
    GridView1.DataSource = data;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    Session["LastIndex"] = data.Count - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is You can assign a unique css class to that particular cell like this

```
grdInvoice.Rows[grdInvoice.Rows.Count-1]
          .Cells[6].CssClass = "className";
```

ad then execute a script after page load(refer to this link here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load))

Using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".className").live("click", function(){
alert('no more rows found to copy');
});
});
```